# Run Android Instrumentation Tests Headless?

Tags: android, testing, ant, command-line

I'm not even sure if this makes sense but is it possible to run instrumentation tests in a headless mode? Currently I run my test suite from the command line like so:

```
ant debug install test
```

Or if I want to focus on single tests like so:

> adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.my.package.testClass#testCase com.my.package.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

Is there a flag I can pass to ant or adb (or both) to run the tests without a UI? I'm not using an emulator. I'm running the tests on my device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a question of running the tests headless, but rather running the emulator headless. Use the `-no-window` switch when starting the emulator from the command line.

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention I'm not using an emulator but running the tests on my device.

Comment: @celesteburke: Then I doubt there is anything you can do, other than to choose test case classes that do not instrument activities, like `AndroidTestCase`.